# JavaScript RegEx expression for interpolation to match "{0-99}"

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to produce my own Interpolation method in an JSON object, like below:

```
var exampleObj = {
firstLabel: "Hello {0}, I like {1} & {2}",
secondLabel: "Luke, I am your {0}",
interpol : function (key, vals) {              
                   key = this[key];
                   return key.replace(/[0-9]/g, function myFunction(i){return vals[i];});
               }    
};

console.log(exampleObj.interpol('firstLabel', ['World','Fish','Chips']));
```

The replace method works however I can only match the number, not the curly bracket and number? What would the correct RegEx syntay be to match any number range between the curly brackets. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just to escape the curly braces as this:

```
return key.replace(/\{[0-9]\}/g, function myFunction(i){return vals[i];});
                    ^------^---- here
```

Btw, as [Rodrigo Lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393095/rodrigo-l%C3%B3pez) pointed in his comment you should also consider having more than 1 digits, so you could use this regex:

```
\{[0-9]+\}
```

Update: as [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol) pointed too, you can shorten your regex by replacen `[0-9]` by `\d`

Comment: I tried that, all i seem to return is 'undefined' 3 times? However I think this is a problem with the function in the replace

Comment: @MarkSandman I don't trust in your `key = this[key]`, I think your problem is not in your regex but in how you treat the variables. Have you debugged the code an checked each variable state?

Comment: @Oriol thanks, updated the answer with your comments